# Getting MasterNotRunningException when using Hbase in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, hbase

I am trying to use Hbase from eclipse on ubuntu, but I get the following:

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Unhandled exception type MasterNotRunningException
    Unhandled exception type ZooKeeperConnectionExceptionr/hbase/lib/hadoop-core-1.1.2.jar TestHBase.jar
```

I've checked that Hbase (Master and Zookeper) is running, and localhost is mapped to 127.0.0.1 in the configuration file.

I've stopped and restarted hbase and got the same results.
What else should I look for?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are able to compile the program properly without any error. Also make sure you have added all the required jars to your project. Do not forget to add the hbase and zookeeper jars.

Comment: I have the following jars referenced in eclipse: /home/hduser/hbase/lib/hadoop-core-1.1.2.jar
/home/hduser/hbase/hbase-0.94.8.jar
/home/hduser/hbase/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar
/home/hduser/hbase/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
/home/hduser/hbase/hbase-0.94.8-tests.jar
/home/hduser/hbase/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar
/home/hduser/hbase/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5. Also this is what is running: jarhduser@ubuntu:~$ jps
29610 SecondaryNameNode
29176 NameNode
11849 HQuorumPeer
29940 TaskTracker
29723 JobTracker
15106 Jps
7289 org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
29392 DataNode
hduser@ubuntu:~$